# Facebook Likes Counter Button Does Not Always Show the Likes Count

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I am very surprised about this problem. If you check along several web sites, you can see that many times the Facebook likes counter does not show any value, although the link has a count value greater than zero. If you check that thing with the Twitter same service, it always works right. It is a programmer or a Facebook team fault? Exists any way to solve this problem?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what the problem is, but chances are it's Facebook's fault (when in doubt blame them).  :)

No, seriously...  the [Facebook Like plugin](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) has several options that let you determine how the total gets displayed (if at all):  standard, count, button_count and box_count.  And if behavior is not what is documented and expected, then chances are Facebook is having a buggy kind of day/week/month.

But if you just need to query for the count, then you can use FQL to pretty easily get that info:
http://www.saschakimmel.com/2010/05/how-to-get-statistics-for-a-facebook-like-button-and-shared-urls/

Comment: Yes, I think the same thing. Is a Facebook problem. Anyway, I think that currently the problem is solved. I you check any web site, you can see that the Facebook likes counter is working fine. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the default behaviour to sometimes not show the count bubble until someone click on the share button.

Here is a description from another blog and how to get around it.

http://kopepasah.com/social-media/facebook/facebook-share-count-button/

Comment: Here is a description from another blog and how to get around it.

http://kopepasah.com/social-media/facebook/facebook-share-count-button/

Answer (score 0):

Check for missing ampersands after parameters in like button's "src" url.

As far as iframe box_count type of like button for Facebook Page is concerned
I had the same problem because I manualy pasted fanpage link in to src of like button witohut `&` or '&amp' after pageid or page name.
I think that if there is no ampersand later parametrs aren't parsed.